# ¿Algo mejor que document.write() para crear plantillas html?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Quisiera saber si existe algo mejor que usar `document.write()` para crear una plantilla que se repita en multiples hojas html, o bien no es considerado buena práctica, porque veo que ningun sitio web lo usan, y sin embargo lo veo como la forma mas sencilla de hacer.

O sea, dentro de los parentesis del `document.write()` escribo la plantilla html, y luego lo meto en un archivo js, el cual sera importado en cada subpágina, luego el contenido unico de cada subpagina se añade con `document.getElementById().innerHTML`.

En este ejemplo de plantilla, quiero hacer un sitio con un flexbox, dentro del cual esta el aside y un div, y a su vez, el div contiene el main y el footer para ambos estén en columna al lado del aside.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    --anchobarra: 300px;
    --margen: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
h1 {margin: 40px; font-size: 23px;}
parts {border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,0); box-sizing: border-box;}
main {font-size: 24px; position: relative;}
.flexconteiner {display: flex; margin: 0 var(--margen) 0 var(--margen)}
.mainfoot { border-right: 1px solid white; width: 100%;}
aside {width: var(--anchobarra); height: 100%; padding: 20px;}
```

```html
<body>
<header class="parts">
    <h1>titulo del sitio</h1>
</header>
    <div class="flexconteiner">
        <div class="mainfoot">
            <main class="parts">
      contenido variable de la subpagina
      </main>
            <footer class="parts">
                contenido variable de la subpagina
            </footer>
        </div>
        <aside id="aside" class="parts">
    contenido invariable
    </aside>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La mejor forma para contarnos todo eso que nos intentas explicar, es añadiendo el código relevante a tu pregunta, editándola.

Comment: según lo poco que te puedo entender, creo que te serviría aprender algún framework como Angular, React, Vue, hace eso y tienes un código estructurado.

Comment: @Alfabravo ya edite el post para añadir un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentaron mas arriba, practicamente lo que quieres es hacer lo que frameworks o librerias como angular, react o vue ya hacen por ti. Pero si quieres realizar algo mas basico sin tanta dependencia puedes utilizar las [Plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings). Esto te permite crear plantillas mas fácilmente e insertarle variables sin concatenar texto y te respeta los saltos de linea. A modo de ejemplo puedes usar una función como témplate

```
function WelcomeView(username) {
   return `<h1>Welcome ${username}</h1>
           <h2>Have a nice day!!</h2>`;
}
```

Este es un ejemplo donde puedes llamar la funcion para insertarlo en tu html desde javascript

```
document.querySelector('header').innerHTML = WelcomeView('El Pepe');
```

Basicamente esto son los componentes de react, pero esto es mucho mas simplificado.

Comment: Excelente respuesta y bien ejemplificada, una lástima quitarle seriedad con tan pésima elección de string en la llamada a la función...

Comment: @Benito-B no son una buena opción ? quizás nadie las usa y yo las e estado usando todo este tiempo :c

Comment: Me refiero al string "El Pepe". Los memes no añaden nada a la explicación

Comment: Aaa ahora entiendo y tienes toda la razón, lo tendré en cuenta de ahora en adelante gracias